# How to Record voice with Audio MimeType in Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, android-mediarecorder

I want to record voice in pure audio format.
currently I am using this code

```
public static void startRecording(String fileName) {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        String mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/abc.mp3";
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }
```

This is showing the file as mp3 but the internal file content mime type is "video/mp4". What I need is any audio mime type.

**EDIT1**
As suggested by **Headuck**, I changed my code to

```
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
mFileName += "/abc.aac";
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

The audio got recorded perfectly with "audio/x-hx-aac-adts" mime type. Thanks **Headuck**.

However my problem is:

I am uploading this file to Google Drive using Cloud endpoints. Then when I open the file it is saying "Oops..! There was a problem in playing this file". I need the file to be played as "MP3" files play.

Does Google Drive supports "ACC" format?. If not please suggest alternatives.
Please help.

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation on `setOutputFormat()` and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html ?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have seen that. But I don' t understand how to record pure audio. please help

Comment: AAC_ADTS is an audio format, if you don't want the MPEG4 container, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552297/how-to-record-raw-aac-audio-files-in-android-using-mediarecorder-aac-adts-doesn

Comment: Did you try using `mFileName += "/abc.mp4";` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to record audio file in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696168/how-to-record-audio-file-in-android)

Comment: Possibly not, and the title may need to be changed to a less misleading one, e.g. How to set audio mime type for recorded mp4 audio.

Comment: Edited my question. please check

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to change the mime type to an `audio` one, you may try the following after `stop()` and `release()` of the recorder (try-catch blocks omitted for clarity):

```
mRecorder.stop();
mRecorder.release();
// Set the mime type to audio
String[] paths = {mFileName};
String[] mimeTypes = {"audio/mp4"};
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
                                paths,
                                mimeTypes,
                                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                        System.out.println("SCAN COMPLETED: " + path);

                                    }
                                });
```